# Return static default value when localization key does not exist

Tags: swift, nslocalizedstring

How can I return a static string (i.e. "AAA") when I am passing a key to NSLocalizedString() that does not exist in the localization file?
I could only find information on how to fall back to a default language but not how to return a hardcoded string in case the key does not exist in the localization file.

This code works for me but I need a fallback option:

```
let localizationKey = "articles_label_" + type.lowercased()
let localizedValue = localizationKey.localized
```

Comment: What is `localized`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSLocalizedString()` takes a parameter `value` which is returned if no localized string is found in the table for the given key.

I infer that `localized` is a computed property added in a `String` extension. Something like that :

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: "MyTable", bundle: Bundle.main, comment: "")
    }
}
```

If you want to add a default value, you should transform this computed property into a function.

```
extension String {
    func localized(defaultValue: String? = nil) -> String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: "MyTable", bundle: Bundle.main, value: defaultValue ?? self, comment: "")
    }
}
```

And use it like that:

```
let localizationKey = "articles_label_" + type.lowercased()
let localizedValue = localizationKey.localized(defaultValue: "AAA")
```

Comment: Great, that worked for me. I used this code: let labelTitle : String = NSLocalizedString(localizationKey, tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "Artikel", comment: localizationKey)